# In propositional logic, is this L the set of simple statements, and the compound statements or just the set of simple statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

On p4 in Chang/Keisler's Model Theory,

> Classical sentential logic is designed to study **a set L of simple statements,
> and  the  compound  statements  built  up  from  them**.  At  the  most  intuitive
> level,  an  intended  interpretation  of these  statements  is  a  ‘possible  world’,
> in  which  each  statement  is  either  true  or  false.  We  wish  to  replace  these
> intuitive  interpretations  by  a  collection  of  precise  mathematical  objects
> which  we  may use  as  our  models.  The first thing  which comes  to  mind  is
> a function F which associates with each simple statement S one of the truth
> values  ‘true’  or  ‘false’.  Stripping  away  the  inessentials,  we  shall  instead
> take a model to be **a subset A of L** the idea is that **S $\in$  A indicates that the
> simple statement S is true**,  and **S $\notin$ A  indicates that the simple  statement S
> is false**.

Which one is L:

- the set  of simple statements, and  the  compound  statements  built  up  from  them, (I guess so from the first sentence)
- the set of simple statements? (I guess so from the last sentence)

Thanks.

Comment: Re: tags, note that this isn't really model theory proper - "model theory" typically refers to the context of *predicate (or higher) logics*, not propositional logics. This isn't universal but it's a good organizing principle to keep in mind, especially w/r/t classical propositional logic which is so simple that [its semantics is hard to distinguish from its syntax](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3371065/28111).

Comment: S. C. Kleene uses the term "model theory" several times in his "Mathematical Logic" in the section on propositional logic.

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is the set of simple statements - or, more commonly, of *atomic propositions* or *propositional atoms*.

(The comma indicates this: "a set $L$ of simple statements, and the compound statements built up from them" versus "a set $L$ of simple statements and the compound statements built up from them." The latter is ambiguous, but the former isn't.)

---

To quickly describe what's going on (since I think the quoted passage is a bit opaque):

The semantics of propositional logic amounts to assigning a truth value from $\{\top,\perp\}$ to each propositional sentence in a "coherent" way (e.g. we can't say that $a\wedge b$ gets $\top$ but $a$ and $b$ each get $\perp$). Such assignments are in fact equivalent to maps from $L$ to $\{\top,\perp\}$: every coherent assignment restricts to such a map, and every such map extends to exactly one coherent assignment. So we can replace the "full valuation" semantcs with this "atomic valuation" semantics, which is simpler in many contexts.

And we can go further and say that maps $L\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$ are themselves equivalent to subsets of $L$ - via the bijection assigning $m:L\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$ to the set $m^{-1}(\top)$, that is, the set of atomic propositions (= members of $L$) which $m$ declares to be true.

This shift, from "the set of maps from all sentences to $\{\top,\perp\}$ satisfying some complicated conditions" to "the set of subsets of $L$," is Chang/Keisler's "stripping away the inessentials."

Comment: Thanks. Is   "coherent"  defined in logic or model theory?

Comment: @Tim No, I'm just using the English word. "Consistent" would fit better, but that's already a technical term in the area. (Actually "coherent" is *also* a technical term, see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+logic), but is far enough away that it's not an issue.)